# invalid conversion from 'int' to 'unsigned char*'

Tags: c++

Obviously, I'm doing something stupid here, can someone help?

The following code:

```cpp
void Encode::getHighNibble(unsigned char* highNibble) {
    
    highNibble = (this->word & 0xe0) >> 1;
    //highNibble |= (this->word & 0x10) >> 2;}
    unsigned char word; // it declared as uint8
```

Gives me the following compilation error:

> invalid conversion from 'int' to 'unsigned char*'

Comment: Once you consider writing a cast in the first place is when you need to be thinking "I'm probably doing something wrong".

Comment: Consider having `getHighNibble()` either 1) `return` the desired value instead of using a pointer parameter, eg: `unsigned char Encode::getHighNibble() { return (word & 0xe0) >> 1; }` or 2) have the parameter be a reference instead of a pointer, eg: `void Encode::getHighNibble(unsigned char &highNibble) { highNibble = ... }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this line:

```
highNibble = (this->word & 0xe0) >> 1;
```

`highNibble` is a pointer (to `unsigned char`).
It can only be assigned to some **address** containing an `unsigned char`, and `(this->word & 0xe0) >> 1` doesn't look like one.

In case you actually wanted to assign the value to the memory where `highNibble` is pointing to, you should use `*highNibble` (i.e. **dereference** the pointer).
Also the type of the expression `(this->word & 0xe0) >> 1` is `int` (as your compiler told you). So you should **cast** it to `unsigned char`.

Fixed version:

```
*highNibble = static_cast<unsigned char>((this->word & 0xe0) >> 1);
```

---

**Edit:**
As @Persixty suggested in the comment below, if you want to extract the high [nibble](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nibble) of a byte, you should actually use the expression: `((this->word) >> 4)` (or `(((this->word) >> 4) & 0x0F)` if `word` was not 8 bit).

Comment: That won't be the high-nibble of course. I think the intention may be `this->word >> 4`. But I'm guessing based on the name `highNibble`.

Comment: @Persixty it's a good guess. Added a note to the answer.

Comment: To explain the word - a nibble usually is 4 bits and typically a byte comprises a high and a low nibble.

Comment: @Sebastian thanks. My answer's addendum actually contains a link to the "nibble" wikipedia page explaining it.